# SKIP "click on 'Download' - Please Wait 5 seconds - click on 'SKIP AD'"

Tags: batch-file, wget

Say i want to get the link of a redirection page but I need to skip some etaps with wget how do I do it ?

What i've tried: loading cookies doesn't work

Comment: please show the batch file you have tried so far

Comment: `wget -w "" -rmH --load-cookies="" "LINK"`

Comment: Start - All Apps - Windows Accessories - Step Recorder. Record your steps

Comment: @CatCat: Hmm what for? My problem concern ads-wget. *ads=redirectional page

Comment: It allows you to click *skip ads*.

Comment: I don't want *me* to click 'skip ads' but wget to do so and go beyond it. 'Record your steps' is just recording what i'm doing, how do you use it with wget?

Answer (score 0):

wget.exe is a tool used to download web pages. You cannot "Skip Ads" by downloading the webpage, because the link generated by skipping ads is created after checking that the ad has been seen and the JavaScript code for executing ads has been successful. (This info is true regarding sites like Adfly, not sites like YouTube.)

We know that this is true because when your adblocker is turned on, the Console reveals errors given by the client. This is checked by the website, and thus we get rejected.

Your theory would've worked for the older versions of Adfly and other link-shorteners.

Comment: *Sorry but not true, in my case my 'adblocker is turned on' and 'the Console' reveals 'the wait' and no errors...
*If the case was really that 'the link generated by skipping ads is created after checking that the ad has been seen' why is it the 'same Adfly redirection link' for me each time? There must be a way...
*About 'other link-shorteners', what kind of batch should I use to success?

Comment: There is no batch to use to succeed. That is why these sites are used so often. That's why the developers there are well payed. That's why this system works.

Because there is no "easy batch skip ad" solution.